# Backbone js passing arguments

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, parameter-passing, built-in

I'm new at reading Backbone js and I have some serious problems with **passing** **arguments** in Backbone js.

```js
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Songs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Song
});
var SongView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "li",
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.model.get("title"));
    return this;
  }
});
var SongsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "ul",
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on("add", this.onSongAdded, this);
  },
  onSongAdded: function(song) { // when object is added to  a collection add event is triggerd 
    // the handler for this event get an argument which is the object that was just added
    //in this case it refers to a song model so we simply pass it to our songView which is responsible for rendering a song an then we use jquery append method 
    // to append it to our list
    var songView = new SongView({
      model: Song
    });
    this.$el.append(songView.render().$el);

  },
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.model.each(function(song) { //
      var songView = new SongView({
        model: Song
      });
      self.$el.append(songView.render().$el);
    });
  }
});
var songs = new Songs([
  new Song({
    title: "1"
  }),
  new Song({
    title: "2"
  }),
  new Song({
    title: "3"
  })
]);
var song_1 = new Song({
  title: "hello"
});
var songsView = new SongsView({
  el: "#songs",
  model: Songs
});
songsView.render();
```

as you can see I have this function: **onSongAdded**
we have some built-in events such as add that get 3 arguments like this:
add(collection, model , options)
how can I use these arguments in my code?
can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`el` option is for pointing the view to an element already existing in DOM. Your item views should be creating new `<li>` elements so you should be using `tagName` option instead.

In your collection view constructor you've defined `el` option and you're passing a different `el` option while instantiating it. If `#songs` is a `<uL>` in DOM, then no use in defining `el: "ul",` in constructor.

Also, there is no need to manually instantiate models, you can just pass objects into collections and collection will do it internally. And don't pass collection as `model`, pass it as `collection`.